Let $f \in \mathbb{A}ut(\mathbb{D)}$. Show that $\lim_{|z|\to 1}|f(z)|=1$.
I have to following problem to solve:
Let $f \in \mathbb{A}ut(\mathbb{D)}$. Show that $\lim_{|z|\to 1}|f(z)|=1$. (Without using the precise form of the automorphism.)
So far I've got the following idea:
Suppose, $\lim_{|z|\to 1}|f(z)|\neq 1.$ Then there exists a sequence $\{z_n\}, |z_n|\to 1$ for $n \to \infty$ s.t. $\omega_n=f(z_n) \to \omega_{\infty}\in \mathbb{D}$. Since $f$ is onto, $\omega_\infty=f(z_\infty)$ . Since $f$ is analytic, the open mapping theorem implies that for large $n$, $\omega_n \in f(B_\epsilon(z_\infty))$. ($\epsilon > 0$ arb.).
I am stuck here. I havent used the 1-1 property of $f$ yet, neither the compactness of $\mathbb{D}$. I believe I can use those two properties to get a contradiction. (I am aware that the open mapping theorem also says that $f$ maps compact sets to compact sets. Don't know if that's useful.)
Help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Odd notation. I think would use $\mathbf{Aut}(\mathbb D)$ or $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb D)$.

@MPW It's actually the notation from Simon's Complex Analysis Book 1.

What is $z_\infty$? You introduced it into your argument without defining it.

Any continuous function maps compact sets to compact sets, that does not need the open mapping theorem.

For large $n$, $\omega_n \in f({B_\epsilon(z_\infty)})$. So $f(z_n)=\omega_{n}$ is in $f(B_\epsilon(z_\infty))$, and since $f$ is injective we get $z_n \in B_\epsilon(z_\infty))$ for all large $n$,  a contradiction to the fact that $|z_n| \to 1$.

Thanks for the answer! I want to clearify: We assume that $f(B_\epsilon(z_\infty))\subset \mathbb{D}$, and $\omega_n \in  \overline{f(B_\epsilon(z_\infty))}\subset \mathbb{D}$ for large $n$. Then by the open mapping theorem, the injectivity and the surjectivity of $f$, we have to have $\overline{B_\epsilon(z_\infty)}\subset \mathbb{D}.$ Which is a contradiction, since $|z_\infty| \in \partial \mathbb{D}$. Is this correct?

Following up question, since $\omega_\infty$ is inside the unit disc, is the closure really necessary?

@FelixU You are right. Closure is not needed.
